# node express.static to read all directory

Tags: javascript, express, frameworks, project

i am working on a Video Portal Project. Videos are categorize in different folders on the server.I am using nodejs technology. My objective is a Function to read a folder a serves all video content in the folder.
currently, the code below serve a specific file instead of a folder. i will 
appreciate your contribution . thanks

```
  let express = require('express');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let path = require('path');

let fs = require('fs');
var ejs=require('ejs');
let port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
let videosPath = './videos/';



let app = express();

/*let logger = function(req, res, next){
    console.log("logging...");
}
app.use(logger);*/

//view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join( __dirname, 'views'));

//routing alternative
//app.use(express.static('public'));


// using body parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));



app.get('/videos/:id',function(req,res){

    fs.readdir(`./videos/${req.params.id}`, (err, files) => {
       console.log(files);
       res.render('pages/index',{videos:files,cateogry_id:req.params.id});
    });

});

app.get('/',function(req,res){
res.render('index');});


app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("server runnung on 4000");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**use [EJS](https://ejs.co/) for template rendering :**

refer this [link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application) for tutorial  ,

create views folder inside root directory of your project , inside which we create our ejs pages for render

now create `index.ejs` file inside **projectName/views/**

inside your `index.ejs` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <h3><%=videos.length+'total videos'%><h3>

  <div class="row">

  <% videos.forEach(function(video)){ %>
       <div class="col-lg-4 my-2">
         <video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
            <source src="<%= '/videos/'+category_id+'/'+video%>" type="video/mp4">
         </video>
       </div>
  <%})%>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

**use [fs module](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_file_system.htm)**

we will use `fs` reading video folder content

inside your videos folder , create folders by category_id , inside that put your videos

like `videos/1/myvideo.mp4`

add this in your **app.js** file

```
var fs = require('fs');
var ejs=require('ejs');

 // set the view engine to ejs
 app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


app.get('/category/:id',function(req,res){

    fs.readdir(`./videos/${req.params.id}`, (err, files) => {
       console.log(files);
       res.render('pages/index',{videos:files,cateogry_id:req.params.id});
    });

});
```

Comment: i appreciate you Saurabh Mistry Thanks for the answer, but i need more clear understanding cos its my first time using the express framework. i am getting exception running the code. i also want all videos in the folder to display simultaneously, that is after reading the folder, the total number of videos should display on a page. thanks in advance.

Comment: @Simon Jerry , ok , I will tell you in detail

Comment: I appreciate mr Saurabh Mistry. ill be expectant.

Comment: I appreciate you mr Saurabh Mistry, but when running the code above i have the following errors:

Comment: @SimonJerry , please add your errors in your question

Comment: @SimonJerry , have you got somwthing  in log , `console.log(files);` ?

Comment: Saurabh Mistry , the cause of the bug is creating the directory folder thats hold the videos. can you please throw more understanding how to create the folder in category id. thanks.

Comment: please read nodejs file systems , above link added , there they have shown how to create folders , how to read , how to delete etc

Comment: @SimonJerry , Do not copy and paste code , you need to clear your fundamentals , how things works in nodejs express js etc , first learn basic modules , then use that modules in your project.

Comment: expressjs , mongoose , fs, moment , request , async , underscore / lodash , nodemailer ....these are the modules which are usefull in nodejs ....learn one by one

Comment: in the log : video is not define.

Comment: @Simon Jerry , paste your current code in your question

Comment: @ Saurabh Mistry , i have edited the first code i past with the current. i also want you to note that the var ejs=require('ejs'); is not used in the main code.

Comment: Thank you , i fix it over the weekend. i used express generator (npm install express-generator --save) to scaffold a new app. videos are categorize in different directories.